# How to design/implement a team members page using SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to design and implement a Sharepoint page in which to present some information regarding  team members. I would like to have for each team member a photo image, full name , role inside the team. This is my first task on Sharepoint and I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already checked [Office Delve](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-office-delve-1315665a-c6af-4409-a28d-49f8916878ca) and decided it's not an contender for your requirement, then you can use [people profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-people-profiles-on-your-page-with-the-people-web-part-7e52c5f6-2d72-48fa-a9d3-d2750765fa05) web part in your SharePoint page. It would show the photo image uploaded by the user in his/her office 365 profile.

[image: People profile]

[image: People profile with descriptive layout]

Answer (score 0):

As the other reply suggests, using [**People web part**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-people-profiles-on-your-page-with-the-people-web-part-7e52c5f6-2d72-48fa-a9d3-d2750765fa05) on a modern site page should suits your need.

The web part would eventually look like this:
[image]

The photo image comes from [**Delve profile**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-office-delve-1315665a-c6af-4409-a28d-49f8916878ca), while the other properties come from **user profiles**, which can only be edited via admin portal (*SharePoint admin center* > *More features* > **User profiles**).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which could give you some more flexibility in regards to UI and showing more information than what comes by default is to use a SharePoint list where you add team members (People Column) with some additional columns and then on-top you could create and add a [List View Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20view%20formatting,be%20applied%20to%20those%20elements.). This is rather advanced so it depends on your skills or if you have someone that could help out.

Some other useful links on this:

- [SharePoint List View Formatting Samples](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-list-formatting/)
- [Profile Card Sample](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/profile-card)

Comment: Unfortunately nobody from my team doesn't have any experience with Sharepoint. Basically this is my first task with it.

Comment: @Elena2020 If you are having trouble getting start with SharePoint Online, you can check out the official training courses that give you a quick start with this product: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-video-training-cb8ef501-84db-4427-ac77-ec2009fb8e23
And here is how to use Web Parts in SharePoint Online: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-web-parts-on-sharepoint-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0